# android merge several images

Tags: android, java-2d

I'm trying to merge up to around 200 images. I'm using the following code but on attempting to merge the 3rd image, the first 2 go away and all that I'm shown is only the 3rd image. In reality, when I'm merging the 50th image, I'm really only dealing w/ 2 images: the one that has 49 images merged and the new image to merge. Here is an excert from my hello world project:

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open(filename);

Bitmap newBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

Drawable drawable = imageButtonFrameView.getDrawable();

boolean isBitmapDrawable = (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable);
if (isBitmapDrawable) {
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
    Bitmap existingBitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAlpha(95);

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(existingBitmap.getWidth(), existingBitmap.getHeight(), existingBitmap.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(existingBitmap, new Matrix(), paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(newBitmap, 0,0,paint);

    newBitmap = bmOverlay;
}

imageButtonFrameView.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you mean by "merge".

Comment: overlay the images so you see both. I use the setAlpha for transparancy to do that. Data member wise, there is only one bitmap object that has all of the images overlayed w/ one another.

Comment: overlay in the context of i would have 60 images if I took a picture of an analog clock showing the second hand move. overlay in the context when I put the 2nd image over the 1st, I will see the second hand pointing to the first second and second second of the minute. the 3rd image overlayed then I would see the second hand point to 1st, 2nd, and 3rd second. etc.